# Field injection with the benefits of constructor injection?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, constructor, field

so I was reading about constructor injection vs field injection and the obvious points in favor of constructor injection is NPE avoiding and better testability, so my question is:
Spring won't allow you to start an application with a missing bean even if it's a field injected one, so no way to get a NPE. And as far as testability goes, you can just mock/spy the beans you want in your tests and it will work as well, so apart from convention is there a real benefit?

Comment: constructor injection means final fields so can't be reassigned by an accident.

Comment: If you write tests and use constructor injection, you can't forget to create mocks for all necessary dependencies. Especially if you add more constructor arguments later on, you are basically forced to adapt your tests.

Answer (score 0):

> Spring won't allow you to start an application with a missing bean even if it's a field injected one

This is not always true, you might mark your beans as being lazy instantiated, so in this case it is quite possible that you will get the NPE, because injection will happen at the point bean is requested(used).

One of the advantages of constructor injection is that it is required injection, as opposite to field. So it is more error-prone.